# MyBB Installation: PHP7 & Nginx File Permissions (Read only file system)

Tags: php, nginx, mybb

I'm having quite the conundrum with file permissions.

> PHP message: PHP Warning:  fopen(/usr/share/nginx/html/dangeroustest/blabla.txt): failed to open stream: Read-only file system in /usr/share/nginx/html/dangeroustest/testwrite.php on line 3" while reading response header from upstream

My current stack is:

- Ubuntu 16.10
- Nginx 1.10.0
- PHP 7.0.6
- MySQL 5.6

Below are the settings I verified:

- In my nginx.conf the worker process is set to run as www-data.
- In my php-fpm pool.d the listeners and user + group are set as
  www-data.
- The files and folders themselves were chowned to www-data:www-data.
- I set the file permissions as appropriate following the MyBB
  installation guide.

Additional checks to ensure settings stuck:

- I have verified the processes are running as the correct users
  through ps aux.
- I do not have SELinux enabled.

CLI PHP will run file system writes, but PHP-FPM will not, when both are run as www-data.

I am at my wits end,

Thanks!

Comment: I think "read only file system" doesn't refer to a file or folder permission problem, but actually to a problem with the file system. What is it ?

Comment: The filesystem is ext4. I am running on a linode VPS.

Comment: Have you tried this checklist : stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory ?

Comment: I think I have the same problem, look at /usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service, you'll see "ProtectSystem=full". This means your file system will be read only for the php-fpm process... Still looking for a good solution...